# Three20 horizontal gradient

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, three20

How can I make horizontal gradient for TTStye?

```
- (TTStyle *) myStyle: (UIControlState)state {
  return [TTShapeStyle styleWithShape:[TTRectangleShape shape] next:
          [TTLinearGradientFillStyle styleWithColor1:RGBCOLOR(60, 60, 60)
                                              color2:RGBCOLOR(30, 30, 30) next:nil]];
}
```

makes Vertical gradient.

Maybe there is some tutorial on Three20 TTStyle's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by copy-past code from TTLinearGradientFillStyle. Several lines changed for achieve horizontal gradient.